# Telnet and opennig command prompt script in linux

Tags: linux, ssh, telnet, expect

I don't have any major scripting experience and I am really confused about the script which I am working on it.

1. I am using dynagen in Linux and created a basic topology with two routers R1(fa0/0=10.1.1.1/port 2101) and R2(fa0/0=10.1.1.2/port 2102).
2. I managed to create a python script and run the routers, I can start and stop them and open consoles, I also can run them from putty and do the same tasks.
3. I need an script to automatic telnet to my Linux and prompt me for username and password /start routers/open command prompt of the device/save the current running configuration file in a folder/.

This what I came up for my 3rd task so far, it telnet to my Linux but doesn't prompt me for username and password, it just print them, and I stuck with the rest.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set timeout 20
spawn telnet x.x.x.x
expect "login:"
expect "Username:"
send "user\r"
expect "Password:"
send "pass\r";
interact
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: what happens if you just type `telnet x.x.x.x` at the command prompt?

Comment: It prompt me with username and password and then telnet to my Linux successfully.

Comment: make sure what you are `expect`ing matches what you see ... it would be more helpful if you copied and pasted the above shell command results to the question ... unfortunately it might be hard to test(for us) as not many telnet servers exist these days ...

Comment: I made couple of changes, it seems working and the script prompt me with username and password. can you please give me a suggestion for my 3rd task, apart from telnet, username and password.

Comment: Is this command "Terminal -e ssh <remote_machine>" can help me with the opening the console of the routers?

Answer (score 0):

What I would do here is use the regexp mode of the expect command, and wait for either "login:" or "Username:". Something like the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set timeout 20
spawn telnet x.x.x.x
expect {
    -re "login:|Username:" {
        send "user\r"
        expect "*assword:"
        send "pass\r"; #After this you may want to expect an appropriate prompt (>, $, #, or whatever) prior to handing control over to user
        interact 
    }
    timeout {
        puts "Timed out while waiting for login prompt"
    }
}
```

Let me know how that goes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried it and it works.now I can telnet to my Linux, now I need an automatic script which start my to routers (R1 and R2)and open their console and save the current running config file to a folder. I have seen so many different scripts and I`m confused. do I have to open those ports for R1 and R2?

Comment: Not sure how your setup works, but in the above script you could remove the "interact" command and replace it with sending whatever commands you need via send/expect pairs.
Basically, anything you can do while interactively logged in via a command-line, you can automate via expect. That is the intent of expect. And since expect is an extension of Tcl, you have at your disposal all the Tcl constructs to do conditional branching and whatever you may need. See [these samples](http://www.pantz.org/software/expect/expect_examples_and_tips.html), they should help you extend your script.

Comment: Correct me if I`m wrong, I think I need to get a cloud connectivity between my Linux and and my routers running so they can ping each other, then add commands "start R1/R2" and "console R1/R2" to my script.

Comment: Basically, I am involve in a project which we intend to have a web page which any user can click on any practice labs, then our frontend server remote desktop to the backend server, telnet to the intended router and open command prompt for the user for the configuration. It is advance for my level but I am happy to have any impact.

Comment: If from the server you have telnetted *into* you now need to initiate new connections out to routers (telnet again?), then you *could* do so by adding into the current script (more send/expect pairs), although I think it would be better to set up a separate expect script on that intermediate server for connecting to each router, and doing whatever you need the script to do, and then run those individual scripts from the intermediate server you have initially telnetted to.

Comment: can I run these commands(dynamips -H 7200 &)and(dynagen topology.txt) with expect?